# Login does not intent in the assigned activity for user's role

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I am creating an app where there is two roles, admin and student.
The admin part is currently doing it's job and logging in the assigned activity.
I don't know how to separate the two roles using realtime database and using snapshot method.

So I added a field "isAdmin" and "isStudent" I was thinking to add at least a value. So everytime a user will login, it will see if the user has "isAdmin" and has value and will direct to other activity the same goes to "isStudent".

The thing now is that, i don't know how to do it, there's no snapshot.hasChild("isAdmin").equals("1") or stuff. The only thing I need is that, the user will be logged in if the account has a field of "isAdmin"/"isStudent" and has value.

here's my code in login part.

```
btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  checkField(userID);
                  checkField(password);
                  if(valid){
                      mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(userID.getText().toString() +"@gmail.com".trim(), password.getText().toString().trim()).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                          @Override
                          public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                              Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Logged in Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                              CheckUserAccessLevel(authResult.getUser().getUid());

                          }
                      }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                          @Override
                          public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                              Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          }
                      });
                  }
            }
        });
```

so basically I am calling a function CheckUserAccessLevel wherein it filters the users role.
So this is my CheckUserAccessLevel function... But it only intents the Admin Account but not the Student Account

```
private void CheckUserAccessLevel(String uid) {
          DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users/"+uid);
          databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
              @Override
              public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                  if(snapshot.hasChild("isAdmin")){
                      Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Logged in as Admin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WelcomeAdminActivity.class));
                      finish();
                  }
                  else if (snapshot.hasChild("isStudent")){
                      Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Logged in as Student", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WelcomeStudentActivity.class));
                      finish();
                  }
                  else {
                      FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                      startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class));
                      finish();
                  }
              }
              @Override
              public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                  Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
          });
    }
```

this is my realtime database

[image]

Comment: because you have assigned  `isStudent =2` and `isAdmin = 1` in database. 1 means true hence it always run admin intent. If not then please add some further information about your fields.

Comment: @ShoaibK. hello, do you know what keyword should I use to to get the value of isStudent? using snapshot.hasChild("isStudent")? there's no snapshot.getstring here tho. im kinda of confused.

Comment: What's the problem with `if(snapshot.hasChild("isAdmin")){`? When you step through this code in a debugger, what do you expect this line to do? And what does it do instead?